# How to retrieve many columns using jpql?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a problem retrieving some info from this class.

```
@Entity
public class Absence {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int absenceId;
private int crn;
private int studentId;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date absenceDate;
```

}

I want to retrieve the following information : studentId, student name ,number of absences. The problem the query doesn't work. 
The query I am using is

```
public List<StudentAbsenceSummary> getSetionAbsences(int crn) {
Query q=em.createQuery("select b.studentId,count(b.studentId)   from Absence b   where            b.crn =:crn group by (b.studentId)")
            .setParameter("crn", crn);
    List<StudentAbsenceSummary> students =q.getResultList();
    return students;
}
```

The class of the retrieved  list

```
public class StudentAbsenceSummary {
private int studentId;
private String name;
private int absenceCount;
```

Comment: How does the query not work?

Comment: does not work because the query returns you a List<Object[]> not a List<StudentAbsenceSummary>. Then you have to manually cast the values and create StudentAbsenceSummary objects. What do you want to achieve?